# Stop propagation on angular-toggle-switch

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, events, toggle

I have a problem with angular-toggle-switch :

I have a form. If this form has been modified and not saved, when I click on a link it display the "#enregistrementModal" modal.

**Modal :**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    Please save your informations before continue.
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
</div>
```

**Html :**

```
<a id="popoverDeleting" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#closingModal">Supprimer mon compte</a>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$('#popoverDeleting').on('click', function (event) {
    if (vm.isLocked == false && $('#submitDonneeForm').prop("disabled") == false) {
        $('#enregistrementModal').modal();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
 })
```

**My problem :**

When I click on my toggle-switch, I can't recover the $event on the javascript. Then I can't stop the propagation and it toggle from true to false in any case.

**Toggle-swicth :**

```
<toggle-switch id="toggleMail" model="vm.isMailChecked" on-change="vm.saveCanalMail()" on-label="Oui" off-label="Non"></toggle-switch>
```

How can I do to stop the propagation of the toggle-switch and display my modal before ?

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the Javascript click-handlers, but the `ng-click` directive. Using it, you can pass `$event` as a parameter:

```
vm.clickHandler = function clickHandler(event) {
    if (vm.isLocked == false && $('#submitDonneeForm').prop("disabled") == false) {
        $('#enregistrementModal').modal();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

and in your HTML:

```
<toggle-switch id="toggleMail" model="vm.isMailChecked" ng-click="vm.clickHandler($event)" ng-change="vm.saveCanalMail()" on-label="Oui" off-label="Non"></toggle-switch>
```